# Use write.csv to export data with unequal rows

Tags: r, list, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to create a series of `data.frame`s and export them to a csv file to use in another program. The format of the file needs to be several columns of equal length, and then a final column that has no data in it. I'm thinking a `list` is the appropriate way to do this, but I cannot get the exported csv file to look like below.

```
alist <- list(c(100,1,2,3,4,5), list(c(200,1,2,3,4,5)), list(c(300)))
```

My final csv file should looks something like this:

```
100 200 300
1   1 
2   2 
3   3 
4   4 
5   5
```

Any suggestions? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code you've tried so far and the reasons why it is not meeting your expectations.  Also, include a sample data set for us to play with.

Comment: I am familiar with using write.csv for dataframes, but I don't think it is possible to create a non-rectangular data frame without introducing NAs, which are not ok for my use. I thought that if I could create a list, and export each element as a column in a csv file, this would solve my problem. I have not been able to get anywhere close to being able to do this and have searched considerably. I have added an example list and what it should look like in the csv file, but beyond this I unfortunately do not have code that is worth posting.

Comment: Any code is good.  

I'd use the solution from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196450/create-a-data-frame-of-unequal-lengths
to create a data frame, then alist[is.na(alist)] <- ""

Comment: I have tried that, I don't believe you can have a data frame with nothing in it. Can't replace NAs with "". @JLLagrange

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understand this question correctly (if Darkness returns...).

`NA` values in R should not pose any problem when writing to a CSV file since there is an argument in `write.table`, "`na`", described as *the string to use for missing values in the data.* Thus, your `NA` values can be replaced with nothing when writing your `data.frame` to a file.

Here's a small example:

#### Create an unbalanced `data.frame`

Notice the empty "300" column and the incomplete "400" column. In R, these are populated with `NA` values.

```
df <- data.frame(`100` = c(1,2,3,4,5), `200` = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                 `300` = NA, `400` = c(letters[1:3], NA, NA), 
                 check.names=FALSE)
df
#   100 200 300  400
# 1   1   1  NA    a
# 2   2   2  NA    b
# 3   3   3  NA    c
# 4   4   4  NA <NA>
# 5   5   5  NA <NA>
```

#### Write the data to a CSV file

Here, I'm writing to a tempfile in the R workspace and viewing it with `cat(readLines(...))` for convenience and demonstration. In actuality, you would probably be writing this to a CSV in your working directory and opening it with another program. Note the correct formation of the CSV file according to the input, but with nothing where an `NA` was in the original data.

```
x <- tempfile()
write.csv(df, file = x, na = "", row.names = FALSE)
cat(readLines(x), sep="\n")
# "100","200","300","400"
# 1,1,,"a"
# 2,2,,"b"
# 3,3,,"c"
# 4,4,,
# 5,5,,
```