# Identifying Duplicate/Unique Teams (and Restructuring Data) in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
 Person Team
   1     30
   2     30
   3     30
   4     30
   11    40
   22    40
   1     50
   2     50
   3     50
   4     50
   15    60
   16    60
   17    60
   1     70
   2     70
   3     70
   4     70
   11    80
   22    80
```

My overall goal is to organize that team identification codes so that it is easy to see which teams are duplicates of one another and which teams are unique.  I want to summarize the data so that it looks like this:

```
 Team   Duplicate1  Duplicate2
  30        50          70
  40        80  
  60
```

As you can see, teams 30, 50, and 70 have identical members, so they share a row.  Similarly, teams 40 and 80 have identical members, so they share a row.  Only team 60 (in this example) is unique.

In situations where teams are duplicated, I don't care which team id goes in which column.  Also, there may be more than 2 duplicates of a team.  Teams range in size from 2 members to 8 members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the format you're wanting, but pretty useful:

```
# using MrFlick's data
library(dplyr)
dd %>% group_by(Team) %>%
    arrange(Person) %>%
    summarize(team.char = paste(Person, collapse = "_")) %>%
    group_by(team.char) %>%
    arrange(team.char, Team) %>%
    mutate(duplicate = 1:n())

Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: team.char

  Team team.char duplicate
1   40     11_22         1
2   80     11_22         2
3   60  15_16_17         1
4   30   1_2_3_4         1
5   50   1_2_3_4         2
6   70   1_2_3_4         3
```

(Edited in the `arrange(Person)` line in case the data isn't already sorted, got the idea from @Reed's answer.)

Answer (score 3):

This answer gives the output data format you asked for. I left the duplicate teams in a single variable because I think it's a better way to handle an arbitrary number of duplicates.

```
require(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Team, Person) %>%   # this line is necessary in case the rest of your data isn't sorted
  group_by(Team) %>%
  summarize(players = paste0(Person, collapse = ",")) %>%
  group_by(players) %>%
  summarize(teams = paste0(Team, collapse = ",")) %>%
  mutate(
    original_team = ifelse(grepl(",", teams), substr(teams, 1, gregexpr(",", teams)[[1]][1]-1), teams),
    dup_teams = ifelse(grepl(",", teams), substr(teams, gregexpr(",", teams)[[1]][1]+1, nchar(teams)), NA)
  )
```

The result:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

   players    teams original_team dup_teams
1  1,2,3,4 30,50,70            30     50,70
2    11,22    40,80            40        80
3 15,16,17       60            60        NA
```

Comment: Good call on sorting first! I'm editing that in to my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using this for your sample data

```
dd<-structure(list(Person = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 11L, 22L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 11L, 22L), Team = c(30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 70L, 70L, 
70L, 70L, 80L, 80L)), .Names = c("Person", "Team"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

You could try a table()/interaction() to find duplicate groups. For example

```
tt <- with(dd, table(Team, Person))
grp <- do.call("interaction", c(data.frame(unclass(tt)), drop=TRUE))
split(rownames(tt), grp)
```

this returns

```
$`1.1.1.1.0.0.0.0.0`
[1] "30" "50" "70"

$`0.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.0`
[1] "60"

$`0.0.0.0.1.0.0.0.1`
[1] "40" "80"
```

so the group "names" are really just indicators for membership for each person. You could easily rename them if you like with `setNames()`. But here it collapse the appropriate teams.

Answer (score 2):

Two more base R options (though not exactly the desired output):

```
DF2 <- aggregate(Person ~ Team, DF, toString)
> split(DF2$Team, DF2$Person)
$`1, 2, 3, 4`
[1] 30 50 70

$`11, 22`
[1] 40 80

$`15, 16, 17`
[1] 60
```

Or

```
( DF2$DupeGroup <- as.integer(factor(DF2$Person)) )
  Team     Person DupeGroup
1   30 1, 2, 3, 4         1
2   40     11, 22         2
3   50 1, 2, 3, 4         1
4   60 15, 16, 17         3
5   70 1, 2, 3, 4         1
6   80     11, 22         2
```

Note that the expected output as shown in the question would either require to add NAs or empty strings in some of the columns entries because in a data.frame, all columns must have the same number of rows. That is different for lists in, as you can see in some of the answers.

---

The second option, but using data.table, since `aggregate` tends to be slow for large data:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, toString(Person), by=Team][,DupeGroup := .GRP, by=V1][]
   Team         V1 DupeGroup
1:   30 1, 2, 3, 4         1
2:   40     11, 22         2
3:   50 1, 2, 3, 4         1
4:   60 15, 16, 17         3
5:   70 1, 2, 3, 4         1
6:   80     11, 22         2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `uniquecombs` from the `mgcv` package:

```
library(mgcv)
library(magrittr) # for the pipe %>%

# Using MrFlick's data
team_names <- sort(unique(dd$Team))
unique_teams <- with(dd, table(Team, Person)) %>% uniquecombs %>% attr("index")
printout <- unstack(data.frame(team_names, unique_teams))

> printout
$`1`
[1] 60

$`2`
[1] 40 80

$`3`
[1] 30 50 70
```

Now you could use something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7196597/937932) to print it in tabular form (note that the groups are column-wise, not row-wise as in your question):

```
attributes(printout) <- list(names = names(printout)
                             , row.names = 1:max(sapply(printout, length))
                             , class = "data.frame")
> printout
     1    2  3
1   60   40 30
2 <NA>   80 50
3 <NA> <NA> 70
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```