# Reshaping a "vector" from long to wide

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, cbind

I have a vector with `rownames`, so it can be considered a "matrix" with 2 columns (one for filename, one for `Topic`):

```
> res
                   Topic
jardine-1.docx.md      1
jardine-2.docx.md      1
jardine-a1.docx.md     1
jardine-a2.docx.md     1
jardine-a3.docx.md     1
jardine-a4.docx.md     3
jardine-a5.docx.md     1
jardine-a6.docx.md     3
jardine-a7.docx.md     3
jardine-a8.docx.md     1
...
```

These are results from the awesome R package on topic modelling, aptly called `topicmodels`.

I want to `cast` this "vector" into *wide* format, just for presentation purposes.

This of courses break "tidy data" principles, where "each observation, or case, is in its own row" (see *Data Transformation with `dplyr`*, available [here](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/).) Nevertheless, the wide format is much neater than the long format:

```
              Topic1       Topic2             Topic3
1  jardine-1.docx.md jk-1.docx.md jardine-a4.docx.md
2  jardine-2.docx.md jk-2.docx.md jardine-a6.docx.md
3 jardine-a1.docx.md jk-4.docx.md jardine-a7.docx.md
4 jardine-a2.docx.md jk-5.docx.md  singtel-1.docx.md
5 jardine-a3.docx.md jk-6.docx.md  singtel-2.docx.md
6 jardine-a5.docx.md         <NA>  singtel-3.docx.md
7 jardine-a8.docx.md         <NA>  singtel-4.docx.md
8       jk-3.docx.md         <NA>  singtel-5.docx.md
9       jk-7.docx.md         <NA>               <NA>
```

This of course can be done in a variety of ways - one of which looks like this (**warning: ugly**)

```
# via cbind
T1=rownames(subset(res, Topic==1))
T2=rownames(subset(res, Topic==2))
T3=rownames(subset(res, Topic==3))
n=max(length(T1),length(T2),length(T3))
length(T1) <- n
length(T2) <- n
length(T3) <- n
cbind(T1,T2,T3)
```

**My question:**

Are there any other better ways of presenting this, considering that all code will be within a R Markdown file for presentation purposes?

Comment: Convert to data.frame and then use "standard" reshaping tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252

Comment: Generally not a good idea to put unequal length vectors into a data.frame. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196450/create-a-data-frame-of-unequal-lengths) for some options If you really must do it.

Comment: By _better ways of presenting this?_, you mean what? How to present the data? Or how to present the reshaping of the data?

Comment: `res` is neither a vector nor a two-column matrix. Use `str` to check what you actually have there.

Comment: @herbaman I mean better ways of *presenting the data*. The reshaping is just a last minute resort of showing all items compactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an interactive table in markdown with the DT package. [Link to vignette](http://rstudio.github.io/DT)

```
library(DT)

datatable(
  dataframe, class = 'cell-border stripe', extensions = c('Buttons', 'FixedColumns'), options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip', scrollX = TRUE, fixedColumns = TRUE,
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
  )
)
```

Explore the vignette, it has a bunch of options such as: formating fields with colors and shapes, enabling user to add or remove columns interactivly, scorling through wide tables, ect.

Comment: thank you for this solution! this is (i believe) what I am looking for. May I check if this interactivity is preserved in an `.Rmd` R Markdown file exported to HTML?

Comment: Sure. Its gonna work as a markdown, flexdashboard, shiny app, etc. You can see examples here: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for more some cleaner code, maybe this will satisfy you ?

```
nmax <- max(table(res$Topic))
ntopics <- 3 # or ntopics <- max(res$Topic) to be more general
build_col <- function(i){rn <- rownames(subset(res,Topic==i)); rn <- c(rn,rep(NA,nmax-length(rn)))} # you may replace NA by "" here for it to look nicer
sapply(1:ntopics,build_col) %>% as.data.frame %>% setNames(paste0("Topic",1:ntopics))

#               Topic1 Topic2             Topic3
# 1  jardine-1.docx.md   <NA> jardine-a4.docx.md
# 2  jardine-2.docx.md   <NA> jardine-a6.docx.md
# 3 jardine-a1.docx.md   <NA> jardine-a7.docx.md
# 4 jardine-a2.docx.md   <NA>               <NA>
# 5 jardine-a3.docx.md   <NA>               <NA>
# 6 jardine-a5.docx.md   <NA>               <NA>
# 7 jardine-a8.docx.md   <NA>               <NA>
```