# How can I change the design of a data frame according to a particular column numbers in R?

Tags: r

I need to reshape my data frame according to the particular column numbers. My data frame has 2 columns and 1127 rows and it is like that;

```
 Class    Gluc
 1         3.7
 1         3.8
 1         3.5
 1         3.9
 4         4.2
 4         5.1
 4         5.8
 4         4.9
 4         5.7
 9         6.6 
 9         6.9
 9         8.1
 9         8.8
 11        7.4
 11        8.3
 11        9.8
```

I want to do that the numbers in column 1 (Class) will be column names and glucose values will be align under these new column numbers according to their class number. Like this;

```
 1     4     9     11
3.7   4.2   6.6   7.4
3.8   5.1   6.9   8.3
3.5   5.8   8.1   9.8
3.9   4.9   8.8
      5.7
```

I used "group_by" and "mutate" functions but they didn't work and also they create a list. I want a data frame not a list.
If someone help me I will be very appreciated..

Comment: Data frames expect rectangular data (all columns should have the same number of rows). Do you want to fill the missing values in the last row with NA for example? Why do you need a data.frame with this shape?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196450/create-a-data-frame-of-unequal-lengths

Comment: @MrFlick while it is correct what you are hypothesizing. I think OP needs a simple reshaping (for example `with pivot_wider()`

Comment: @MrFlick I need this data frame because I want to find cmax , tpeak.. for each 'class' number. For example 3.9 for class 1, 5.7 for class 4..  I had used "pivot_wider" function before but it gave me a 'list' and I couldn't find what I want.

Comment: You don’t need to reshape for that purpose. If you use group_by from dplyr you would be able to do those calculations with the data in its original structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do it with `pivot_wider()` to get it work smooth we first group by `Class` and add row numbers:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Class) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Class, values_from = Gluc) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
   `1`   `4`   `9`  `11`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   3.7   4.2   6.6   7.4
2   3.8   5.1   6.9   8.3
3   3.5   5.8   8.1   9.8
4   3.9   4.9   8.8  NA  
5  NA     5.7  NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but it is a list not a data frame and I cannot convert it to data frame

Comment: what is a list my output or your original data?

Comment: the type of the outcome is a 'list'. So can not find cmax, tpeak etc in this type. If you have a solution to find them (cmax, tpeak) in a 'list', I will be very appreciated..

Comment: The type of outcome is `1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"` and not a list. Try this: `library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Class) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Class, values_from = Gluc) %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~max(., na.rm = TRUE), .names= "max_{.col}"))`