R function to create a matrix with differing number of rows
I'm trying to create a new 4-column matrix. Each column are from a different data frame.
The problem is that the four original data frame don't have the same row length, so I can't use the classic code.
This is my code
New=data.frame(a$col2,b$col2,c$col2,d$col2,)

And I have this error
Error in data.frame(...
arguments imply differing number of rows:


You may try the approaches mentioned in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196450/create-a-dataframe-of-unequal-lengths

So you need to either delete some data or add data since matrices are rectangular...
